# params appearing in params[:format] when passing to _path route helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a function which calls a _path helper function with several parameters:
`v2_specific_path(user, filter_params)`
This works great, and in the controller method that handles this path I see both `user` and `filter_params` and their values.

In fact if I try to print out `params` they don't show up, but if I print out either one of them then they print out fine. `filter_params` has a helper function which builds a hash from several `params[:keys]` so that might be the reason.

What I'm trying to do is add another set of parameters to the function call:
`v2_specific_path(user, new_params, filter_params)`
Since I'm trying to add some functionality which requires passing some information to the underlying controller that resolves this request.

The problem is that this doesn't work and seems to screw things over:

1. If I put them in the middle: `v2_specific_path(user, new_params, filter_params)`, then all the other params work great, but `new_params` actually appear inside `params[:format]` as: `params[:format]="param1=4&param2=hi`
2. If I put them at the end: v2_specific_path(user, filter_params, new_params) then `filter_params` doesn't get parsed at all and appears in `params[:format]` but `new_format` **does appear to be parsed** and appear in `params` correctly

I can't seem to figure out why this is happening. I've made sure I have correct `params.require/params.permit` values in the controller.

Any help is appreciated, if anyone has any other alternatives to passing values from `application_helper` to a controller (via _path, or some shared variable) that would also help immensely

Thank you!

Comment: an actual code block might help in understanding what's really happening

Comment: Please post the code for the `filter_params` method. Because this is where you probably need to make the change.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone seeking a solution to this:

I fixed this by doing two things:
1) created proper **new** routes which suited my implementation (I tried to do something a bit too clever and decided to just create new relevant routes instead of doing something too dynamic
2) I added the params I needed in to the routes: `/something/:param1/whatever/:param2` etc.

This worked for me